# Download contents of file shared using dropbox API

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api, dropbox-sdk-js

I am working on a chrome extension wherein the users can store the files in their dropbox account. As mentioned in the dropbox api [share file link](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#shares), I used that endpoint to generate a file sharing link which generates a compressed/shortened sharing url like `https://db.tt/c0mFuu1Y`. Now my query is that how can I use the dropbox api to get the contents of the file using this shared link, somewhat like what happens [here](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#files-GET) for the files owned by the user.

Answer (score 0):

See https://www.dropbox.com/help/201.

If you have a shortened link, like the example you gave, you'll want to fetch that first and get the `Location` header on the 302 response. That will give you the full (non-shortened) share link. From there, you can apply the technique described in the link above... add the `?raw=1` query parameter and just download the contents.

Comment: any idea on how to capture a 302 status in jquery ajax or xmlhttprequest ? I looked up a lot but couldn't find any solution on how to grab that status and location header, although I can see it under `Network` tab in browser console that the ajax request to compressed url returns with a 302 status.

Comment: I suspect that you can't do this. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199099/how-to-manage-a-redirect-request-after-a-jquery-ajax-call. I'd recommend doing this part on the server (assuming you have a server somewhere).

Comment: I found the solution within the dropbox api itself, to get the non-shortened url we have to pass the query parameter `short_url=false` and that directly sends over the target url which can then be used to apply the `raw=1` fix to get the contents directly.